# Installing NuGet package with Specific Version property set on Visual Studio assembly reference

Tags: nuget, version, assembly-resolution

When I run nuget install package, my assembly reference is set with "Specific Version" false. I want this set to true when installing a package, is this possible?

I need to prohibit the assembly resolution to use older versions of the package assemblies.

Comment: Did you figure anything out? I have the opposite problem; I want to set the flag to false, because we use latest versions in our automatic build system.

Comment: @Julius: No, I didn't. Don't you get that behaviour by default?

Comment: Yes, and I do not know why. I added a question for it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32864732/what-controls-the-specific-version-property-of-a-reference-in-a-nuget-package). Could be considered a duplicate of this one.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're not using the BindingRedirect for assembly installed via nuget package in your configuration file. That will do the needful for assembly resolution to specific version. Few Nuget packages add this setting automatically that can be removed to use only specific version of assembly.